# What's a term for something that's not right and not wrong?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need to write a science lab report where the data proves my hypothesis neither right or wrong.

> The results of the experiment were ____, and did not support or reject the hypothesis.

Comment: Surely you mean 'neither confirms nor disproves my hypothesis'.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please review the guidance for [tag:single-word-requests], as well as the site [tour] and [help] if you are new to the Stack Exchange network. In brief, however, it sounds like the results of your experiment are *inconclusive* with regards to the hypothesis, because you cannot conclude whether they are "right" or "wrong."

Comment: If @EdwinAshworth's comment is right, then you probably want to say that the data are inconclusive. If you literally meant that your hypothesis is proved to be neither right nor wrong, then the word I'd use to describe the hypothesis (not the data) is "meaningless".

Comment: 'A better word for “unanswered” ' was closed. 'Inconclusive' was given there.

Answer (score 1):

[Inconclusive](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inconclusive).

> without final results or outcome:
>
> *inconclusive experiments*.

[Dictionary.com]